# getting more carbs in liquid form

Tags: weight-gain, carbohydrate, juice

I used a macros calculator to find out how much to eat for a gain goal. I used chicken, eggs, and brown rice to keep the math simple.

After cooking one days worth of food, I wasn't able to finish it all throughout the day. The most difficult part was the sheer volume of brown rice that I needed to eat for the carbs metric. I know that just drinking soda or juice is not a suitable way to get carbs since the lack of fiber will cause the sugar to be stored as fat.

I'm going to use less food and more protein shakes to make for less chewing and eating, but I'm curious about two other strategies for getting more carbs into my diet:

1. Blending (pulverizing whole fruits/vegetables) - If I get a vitamix, I can drink a good amount of carbs and fiber throughout the day. Is this worth trying?
2. Drinking juice and taking fiber supplements - Would this even work?

Any other liquid strategies are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that just drinking soda or juice is not a suitable way to get carbs since the lack of fiber will cause the sugar to be stored as fat.

I'm not sure where that came from. Fiber can't be digested as easily as complex or simple carbs. That's usually why people subtract them from the total amount of carbs (though I don't do this. It just complicates things.)

Non-fibrous carbs go to glycogen, some go to help build muscle, and some to fat regardless of fiber composition of the total meal. The body decides what goes where depending on necessity.

Total daily fiber requirements for the average adult, male human is about 25-30g of fiber a day (some sources say as much as 40g). So most of your carb sources should have fiber for this reason, but you can pad out the rest of your carbs with anything once you hit this.

I like apple juice or sweet tea. Flavored coffee syrups go great with coffee, and you can also mix them in other things.

Oatmeal is a great carbs source for this reason. It's very bland on its own. You can add sugar, honey, fruit punch powder packet, or flavored syrup to it to enhance it with carbs without touching your other macros. It's also very fibrous on its own so you can mix fiber with carbs.

I also do know people who like the Vitamix solution. Sometimes eating a massive amount of fruit is cumbersome. I'm not sure you should buy one just for this reason though.

Comment: When you say “the body decides what goes where depending on necessity”, I’m wondering how I can tell my body to send carbs to build muscle and not store fat. Does more frequent, intense exercise help influence the body’s decision? The central problem I’m having is that I have abs at 170lbs, but once I get up to 180lbs, my abs and definition go away.

Comment: Heavy weightlifting with progressive overload will help prioritize muscle building over fat gain, but you should be doing this *anyway* if your goal is to build muscle. There's really nothing you can do to "hack" the body to only do one or the other. It will always do both. Lifting progressively heavier/more weight over time will help tip the balance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically looking for a liquid carbohydrate solution there are products on the market specifically made for this. You can simply search for `carbohydrate supplement` to find a product that you can purchase near you.

Nutrition from real food is always your best bet and maybe there are a few other options you can add beside brown rice:

- Oats
- Bananas
- Chickpeas

A second thing to consider, because I made this mistake, is that there is a big nutritional difference when you consider *uncooked* and *cooked* rice. If you're measuring 100 g of *uncooked* rice, cooking it, and then eating it, make sure you're counting your macros as 100 g of *uncooked* rice. Otherwise, reweigh the *cooked* rice for you macros.

- [*Uncooked* rice](https://www.eatthismuch.com/food/nutrition/brown-rice,4804/): 76 g of carbs per 100 g.
- [*Cooked* rice](https://www.eatthismuch.com/food/nutrition/brown-rice,4805/): 24 g of carbs per 100 g.